# Error when passing negative integer to a function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

If I define a function in OCaml, for example `let f x = x + 1;;` and then I try to call it passing a negative number
 `f -1;;` it gives to me the following error

```
Error: This expression has type int -> int
   but an expression was expected of type int
```

Why this error occurs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it comes from the precedence of the parser. The compiler believes that `f -1` means you want to subtract `f` by `1`. It has been complained about for ages now.

Typing in `f (-1)` or `f ~-1` will solve your problem (the later using the "explicitly unary minus").

UPDATE:

As stated in the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL%28~-%29):

> Unary negation. You can also write - e instead of ~- e.

Basically, `-` can be used both as a binary operator `4 - 1` and a unary operator `-1`. But, as in your case, there can be confusion: `f - 1` is "f minus one" and not "f applied to minus one". So the `~-` operator was added to have a non-confusing unary minus as well.

Note that the spaces are not significant here, and that won't change because a lot of already existing code may contain operations without space.