# OCaml: "int_of_float -0.7" returns "Error: This expression has type float -> int, but an expression was expected of type int". Why?

Tags: ocaml

OCaml newbie here.

As I read through [an introductory book for OCaml](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0-OCaml-%E3%80%9C%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E5%9E%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E7%A4%8E%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89GUI%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%80%9C-%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E5%B5%90%E6%B7%B3-ebook/dp/B00QRPI1AS), I stumbled on an error, which I don't get why arises.

```
(On toplevel) # int_of_float -0.7;;
Error: This expression has type float -> int
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

I tried the following also:

```
# float_of_int -0.7;;
Error: This expression has type int -> float
       but an expression was expected of type int

# -0.7;;
- : float = -0.7
```

While the expression "-0.7" is interpreted as "float" type, "int_of_float -0.7" doesn't return the expected value (which is 0 in this case). MoreOver, since "float_of_int -0.7" also doesn't return the expected value, -0.7 is not interpreted as float or int.

I don't get how "int_of_float" and "float_of_int" interpret their operands. I've visited the original [github](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml), but I couldn't find the reference to those two libraries.

How are those libraries working inside? Teaching where the source codes are is also a great help.

Comment: `int_of_float - 0.7` is parsed as the subtraction between a function and a number, you either need to add parentheses or use the unary floating-point negation operator, e.g. `int_of_float ~-.0.5`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/8984661/124319

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044873/error-when-passing-negative-integer-to-a-function-in-ocaml/34044948#34044948

Comment: @coredump Thank you for the clarification. My question is solved completely.